# Moving files in Laravel 5.2 using Storage::move

Tags: php, laravel, path, laravel-5

I am looking to move files in Laravel 5.2 using Storage::move. The code I am using is below:

```
$file = basename($m);
            $new_path= base_path('mailbox_archive/'.$file);

Storage::move($m, $new_path);
```

I am getting the following error message:

> [League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException]
>   File not found at path:
>   Users/JamesParsons/Dropbox/virtual/mailbox/17_10-08
>   -16_20-49-17.json

The paths are as follows:

```
$m=/Users/JamesParsons/Dropbox/virtual/mailbox/17_10-08-16_20-49-17.json

$new_path=/Users/JamesParsons/Dropbox/virtual/mailbox_archive/17_10-08-16_20-49-17.json
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to use full explicitly : `$old_path= base_path('mailbox/'.$file);` then : `Storage::move($old_path, $new_path);`

Comment: No luck unfortunately @Maraboc

Comment: are you using this file after moving it in your below code (code after this line `Storage::move($m, $new_path);`)? or there is no other code ?

Comment: There is no other code, this is the final action to move the file and clear the directory

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to access/move a file on your computer. But you are in a host/vm/server.  This will not work as your inside the VM etc and therefore cannot access your dropbox folder.

Comment: But the same process would work on a live server? @Simon Davies?

Comment: for it to work on your local / vm /server etc then you would need the folder(s) /Users/JamesParsons/Dropbox/virtual/ within your server/site, and set it up using the storage disk config.  The code cannot escape the server and access your HD

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem as long as I know it will work once live. It's the final action in the command and everything tested to that point so not a problem

Comment: So the folders will be on the live server? If so where, and coudl you not replicate this on you app, so you local test pass etc?

Comment: The folders will be on the live app, mailbox and mailbox_archive will sit in the root of the app. The root for the app is virtual and that is the same name as the root on the live server. This is a branch working off an already functioning app.

Comment: ok but if you could set it up on your local v/server etc then you can ensure alls ok, but good to know

Answer (score 0):

I changed the above from

```
Storage::move($m, $new_path);
```

To

```
File::move($m, $new_path);
```